# postgres update multiple columns in single query

Tags: postgresql

I want to update multiple columns in table which are conditionally dependent on each other.

```
create table justtable(a numeric, b numeric, c numeric,d numeric,e numeric)
insert into justtable values(1,10,10,10,10)

select * from justtable
returns - 1;10;10;10;10

update justtable set b=10, c=b*2, d=c*2, e=d*2 where a=1;

select * from justtable
returns - 1;10;20;20;20
```

I want it to return 1;10;20;40;80.
Is it possible to do this is single query else will have to write multiple updates in sequence. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would use some arithmetic to rewrite the query, the `b` column is the minimum base for arithmetic, so we might get formulas like below.

- c = 2 * b
- d = 4 * b
- e = 8 * b

you can try to use this

```
update justtable 
set b=10, c=b*2, d=b*4, e=b*8 
where a=1;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=472d215c2d041fc466a66d6f75b49533)